# How to order the pandas dataframe heading as proper dataset like the below second output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below code generate the first output as given below . I have multiple output as a dataframe for each variable like Age_Bin.

```
    df1 = ( df.groupby(['Age_Bin','Outcome'])['Cat_Bin'] .size() .unstack(fill_value=0) .add_prefix('Outcome_') ) 

                     df_A = df1.assign(Total_cnt=lambda x: x.sum(1)).join(df1.div(df1.sum()).add_suffix('%')) 

        print (df_A)
```

First output:

```
       Outcome   Outcome_0 Outcome_1 Total_cnt Outcome_0% Outcome_1% 
       Age_Bin 
         Age1          1       3        4         0.25      0.6 
         Age2          1       1        2         0.25      0.2 
         Age3          2       1        3         0.50      0.2
```

df_B is similar as df_A but for another variable. For example df_B given below

```
print (df_B)

          Outcome   Outcome_0 Outcome_1 Total_cnt Outcome_0% Outcome_1% 
           LTM_Bin 
             LTM1          1       3        4         0.25      0.6 
             LTM2          1       1        2         0.25      0.2 
             LTM3          2       1        3         0.50      0.2
```

If I use concat function like below

```
Df_final = pd.concat([df_A,df_B],axis=0)
```

I am getting an error due the first column structure in the first output . 
If I have output like second output then I believe it is easy to apply concat.

Second output :

```
    Age_Bin Outcome_0 Outcome_1 Total_cnt Outcome_0% Outcome_1% 
    Age1        1         3       4           0.25      0.6 
    Age2        1         1       2           0.25      0.2
    Age3        2         1       3           0.50      0.2
```

Comment: What is `df_B`? Also, your example code computes `df1` in the first line and `df_A` in the second line, but then prints `df`. Also, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Questions has been edited to include more information

Comment: For me it working nice, what is error message? Do you want `df_A.index = df_A.index.astype(str)` and `df_B.index = df_B.index.astype(str)` before concat?